# How do you pre-compute a scoring system from the database?

Tags: database, scoring

Stackoverflow displays your reputation next to your username. I suppose it doesn't hit the database to calculate your score on every page render (or perhaps it does?). Would there be a total score field in the users table that gets updated when someone upvotes me?

What is the best practice for these kind of systems? I'm sorry if it's an obvious question, I'm new to databases.

Comment: +1. Having asked this question to myself for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you log in, the number is pulled from the database along with all your users information.

It can be a user object. That user object has a property score which is initialized to whatever that number is in the database when you just log in.

As you go around the website and do stuff, the property is updated but not the database.

You can then update the database only once when the object user is destructed (either by logout or closing the browser) or after a certain amount of time.

Comment: The property is updated in the in-memory cache and also pushed or queued to the persistance layer (db in this case)...you can not rely on user logging out or closing the browser to update your entities.

Answer (score 0):

I think the general answer for such a general question is: Caching! The idea of caching might be simple, but it's not always easy to do it right. I would assume that SO not only stores your total score. It stores all "events" which add to your score. Your total score is calculated out of these "events". So to the total score is already some kind of precalculated or cached value. If you don't want to hit the database for each request, you can cache the values in memory. Memcached is used often for such jobs, but there are other options of course.